# How can I trade in U.S stock exchange living in India by choosing the broker in U.S?

Tags: united-states, stocks, india, ipo, stock-markets

I would appreciate if you kindly suggest an answer for this question.Anything incomplete in this question should be assumed.

And also please suggest which is the best brokerage firm/broker for this kind of trading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OptionsXpress](https://www.optionsxpress.com/) includes India in the list of countries where is possible to open an international account to invest in the US Stock Market. They just merged with Charles Schwab and they have a nice online trading platform. Stocks and ETFs are little bit pricey..

Get in touch with them to get more information.

Answer (score 4):

It is more easier if you select a Broker in India that would allow you these services. The reason being the broker in India will follow the required norms by India and allow you to invest without much hassel. Further as the institution would be in India, it would be more easy for resolving any disputes.

ICICI Direct an Indian online broker allows one to trade in US stocks.
For more details refer to ICIC Direct.
Reliance Money also offers limited trading in US stocks.

Selecting a Broker in US maybe more difficult as your would have to met their KYC norm's and also operate a Bank account in US. I am not aware of the requirements.

For more details visit ICICI Direct website. Refer to http://www.finance-trading-times.com/2007/10/investing-in-us-stocks-and-options.html for a news article.

TDAmeritrade or Charlesschwab are good online brokers, however from what I read they are more for US nationals holding Social Security. Further with the recent events and KYC norms becoming more stringent, it would be difficult for an individual [Indian Citizen] to open an account directly with these firms.

Comment: Can an Indian citizen open a Bank account in US without a US Visa?

Comment: Thanks Dheer.Would it be a wise decision that I open an account with TDAmeritrade or Charlesschwab etc.

Comment: @ Himanshu: updated my answer. Any concern in going with the Indian borker house that tie up with US brokrage house to delivery essentially the same service?

Comment: I am not sure if an ordinary individual sitting in India can open an account in the US without visiting. I know of individuals who have opened an account on Business Visa without social security number, but Indian Passport sufficing. This was way back in 2005-06. With the current KYC norms becoming more stringent, it may not be possible for an individual to open a US account.

Comment: @Dheer Thanks for your answer Dheer.Will keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

i have been trading with dollarbird Trading firm for past 1 year there is absolutly no problem everything is fine you can google them to find anything about them.they have provided me with LASER trading platform which requires a bit of training as in to know the software but i can say one thing trading in US Equity market exp. is very diffrent from indian market they are very mature market and highly liqd and have good volatality to trade best equity market to trade with great trading platform you should have a exp. to trade on US equity it is diffrent

Comment: Hi hitendra, welcome to Money.Stackexchange.com.  Please do not add new answers, but rather edit your existing answer.  In this case I've deleted your old answer.