# Investing in US Markets from India

Tags: united-states, investing, india, stock-exchanges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I trade in U.S stock exchange living in India by choosing the broker in U.S?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/11029/how-can-i-trade-in-u-s-stock-exchange-living-in-india-by-choosing-the-broker-in)

I don't reside in US but would like to invest in US markets. If not in specific stocks but at least in the indices. Is it possible for me to do so? If yes, what should be the procedure. I don't plan to visit US in near future, so the process should be completely online. Needless to say I've a trading accounts in India (if that is of any help). Also I'm a retail investor. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to invest in your home country? You don't have any broker in your home country with access to US market? Doesn't sound right.

Comment: Also, consider this question which sounds very similar to yours: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/struggling-to-find-a-broker-for-international-investors-with-a-small-amount-to-s

Comment: Please specify your home country.

Comment: My home country is India and never heard of any Indian broker which can allow me to directly buy into US stocks. Though heard of Charles Schwab but it seems they don't have a no-frills product for such requirement. I want to invest in very small amounts over a long period of time.

Comment: Edited to be more specific. @Harshal, what is the legal limitation on foreign currency trading in India? I know there's a limitation, are you aware of it?

Comment: @Dheer thanks for the link. I didn't find the question when I searched it. It answers my query. We can close this question now.